# Matlab and HDL code generation

Tags: verilog, matlab, hdl

I have a project involving audio on a Xilinx Spartan6 FPGA. The goal of the project is to make an audio processor using HDL (mostly educative and for fun). It's basically a pipeline of audio effects that can be configured using SPI. I wanted to use this project to get an introduction to Matlab HDL coder.

I design the audio effects in Simulink then implements them in Verilog. I would like to improve my work method and hopefully use the Simulink design to implement directly in my FPGA, which HDL coder is supposed to do.

My audio signal is sampled at 48KHz, but my FPGA is clocked at 96MHz. When I design the effects in Simulink, I set my sampling frequency to 48KHz, then uses blocs like adders/multiplier,etc that all execute within a single step. In my verilog code, the implementation I do are not always executed in a single clock cycle. For example, I use a custom module for scaling samples that is optimized in space but takes as much clock cycle as there is bits in the operand.

When comes to simulate in Matlab, setting my sampling frequency at 96MHz is too slow to get a real gain in efficacity. The time I save by not writing Verilog is lost waiting for the simulation to process few audio samples.

How do people uses HDL coder to overcome this very obvious problem? 
Do professionals have very powerful simulation machines? Do they wait? Do they uses FPGA powerful enough not to need to worry about saving some elements like DSP slices?

Is there a way to have 2 versions of the same bloc, like a simulation v.s. an implementation one?

Thank you

Comment: Verilog has `define, that may be helpful here.

Comment: I think you may not have read the complete question. It's about Matlab/Simulink HDL coder, not Verilog. Or maybe I don't see what you mean. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Sound like you need to try to [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)) your design wherever possible.

Comment: There is, the code generator creates an entity for each simulink block (burns logic) but you can. Inform the gen to use your own code.  On a block basis